# Are there CM complete intersections of arbitrarily large degree and codimension?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-multiplication, complete-intersection, hypersurfaces

For every $d, c$ does there exist a smooth complete intersection $X \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ of codimension $c$ and multidegrees $d_1, \dots, d_c \ge d$ such that the Mumford-Tate group of $X$ is abelian?

The only way I know how to produce such things is by explicit example e.g. the Fermat hypersurface. Are there any tools that will let me answer the above?